# redirecting output of `paste` command with periodic input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I was trying to combine multiple output of commands into a single output by using the `paste` command. However, it didn't work as expected, and I minimized the problem into the following:

```
paste <(while : ; do; echo "test"; sleep 1; done;) | cat
```

(the `while...` part is actually a executable with periodic output, and `cat` is a script for logging in what I'm working on)

I expect this to output `test` repeatedly with interval of 1 seconds, but running this  prints no output.

Substituting `sleep 1` with `sleep 0`, or `paste` with `cat` works as expected, but I want to keep using `paste` to combine multiple output.

Why doesn't the above snippet work, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Is it really correct to put paste <(somecommands) ?  What does that mean to redirect standard input from a command in brackets?

Comment: @xpusostomos It is called *"Process substitution"*, see  https://medium.com/factualopinions/process-substitution-in-bash-739096a2f66d

Comment: found that [python version of paste](https://gist.github.com/joseffrank/65f1cf0554170985fe52c9953dc14e2a) works (by running with `python -u paste.py`), but don't know why it doesn't with coreutils paste

Comment: Your command has a syntax error in the first place (The `;` just after the `do` is wrong). If you fix that, it will seem to be not working but actually it works. The output of `paste` is buffered since it is piped through. You must wait enough time for data to end up in the output. And this maybe a very long time. Try with `sleep 0.01` to shorten it.

Comment: What is a _**periodic** output_? Periodicity means that the same shows up forever in regular intervals, and I don't understand what this means in the content of an output.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by M. Nejat Aydin, `paste` buffers its output (but `cat` doesn't, it seems). To make `paste` not buffer its output, use `stdbuf`.

```
stdbuf -i 0 -o 0 -e 0 paste <(while : ; do; echo "test"; sleep 1; done;) | cat
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `cat`  also buffers the output, but perhaps it behaves differently depending on whether stdout it is attached to a tty. Aside from this, the OP for sure does not really use a `cat` at the end of the pipe, which would be pointless. From my understanding, his `cat` is more like a placeholder for the application which really uses the pipe.